# Flip Flopping Of Computer Screen To Windows Screen

Tags: windows-8

My windows screen is flip flopping continuously between desktop and windows.

I have also checked task manager.
1.Windows log-in application, 2.windows start up and  3. windows session manager is coming repeatedly.

I have also tried by google search( windows key+I).I am unable to apply any method.
when google chrome is opened same tab is coming again and again.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "I shut down the system removed all the cables like power cable ,LAN cable ,Usb and restarted the system and now it works fine"

Comment: Actually I said what I observed , may be that may be an coincidence, I donot know what actually made that flip flopping stop , I tried about 6 or more times restarting my system...

Answer (score 1):

First step would be to uninstall the keyboard.

If the problem goes away then you know it is the keyboard itself.

If not, and if your mouse works, you might go into device manager and see what HID (Human Interface Devices) it sees that might be feeding keystrokes into the computer.

Comment: How to go to device manager is it through setting  - > PC and devices ?

Comment: Depending on the version of WIndows..  Windows 7 has Device Manager in the control panel, perhaps under Administrative Tools.  But in all versions you can type in "Computer Management" and it will be one of the choices once that opens.  .  Also, if you right-click on "My PC" or "Computer" it is one of the options there (in desktop mode). .     But I am very curious to know if the behavior stopped when you disconnected the keyboard.

Comment: Myn is Win8 as can be seen in the tag,No I don't know what hapened I shut down the system removed all the cables like power cable ,LAN cable ,Usb and restarted the system and now it works fine Inever disconnected the keyboard

Comment: That's great.  On my workbench PC sometimes I find strange activity because I have let something hold down my space bar or the enter key on the far right....    In any case, I'm glad you got it to work.

Comment: Thanks for sparing some time for this question!.but I still don't know why was that happening